# My cgal code 3d delaunay triangulation wrong

Tags: 3d, cgal, delaunay

I pass in the point to get triangulate and spit out cell data. But the value spit back is wrong as the cell data is violate the principle of triangulation.

```
   typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel K; 
   typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_3<K> Delaunay; 

   std::vector<K::Point_3> points; 
   std::map<Delaunay::Vertex_handle, int> index_of_vertex; 


   points.push_back(K::Point_3(-400.0, 0.0, 0.0)); 
   points.push_back(K::Point_3(200, 400.0, 0.0)); 
   points.push_back(K::Point_3(200, -400.0, 0.0)); 
   points.push_back(K::Point_3(0.0, 0.0, 600.0)); 
   points.push_back(K::Point_3(0.0, 0.0, -600.0)); 

   //And here I push the vector to Delaunay 
   Delaunay dt(points.begin(), points.end()); 

   // Keep track of vertex used 
   for (Delaunay::Finite_vertices_iterator it = t.finite_vertices_begin(); it != dt.finite_vertices_end(); ++it, ++j) 
    { 
        index_of_vertex[it.base()] = j; 
    } 

   // Iterate though and extract vertex and index in cell. 
   for (Delaunay::Finite_cells_iterator itCell = it.finite_cells_begin(), itend = dt.finite_cells_end();              itCell != itend; itCell++) 
    { 
        vector<double> verts; 
        vector<int> indx; 

        int ind0 = index_of_vertex[itCell->vertex(0)]; 
        int ind1 = index_of_vertex[itCell->vertex(1)]; 
        int ind2 = index_of_vertex[itCell->vertex(2)]; 
        int ind3 = index_of_vertex[itCell->vertex(3)]; 

        K::Point_3 v0 = points[ind0]; 
        K::Point_3 v1 = points[ind1]; 
        K::Point_3 v2 = points[ind2]; 
        K::Point_3 v3 = points[ind3]; 

        // Store the vertex 
        verts.push_back(CGAL::to_double(v0.x())); 
        ... 
        verts.push_back(CGAL::to_double(v3.z())); 

        // extract the index 
        int ind00 = Delaunay::vertex_triple_index(0, 0); 
        ... 
        int ind32 = Delaunay::vertex_triple_index(3, 2); 

        // Store the index 
        indx.push_back(ind00); 
        ... 
        indx.push_back(ind32); 
  }
```

// ---- Expect ---- 
As you see up there. I have 5 point (-400.0, 0.0, 0.0), (200, 400.0, 0.0),
(200, -400.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 600.0), (0.0, 0.0, -600.0). 
So if it spit out correctly, I will likely be two cell with vertex at index
of (0, 1,2,3) and (0,1,2,4).

// ----- Result ---- 
But some how it split out wrong ( 0, 1, 2, 3) and (0,1,3,4). If I reduce the
z of 3 and 4 down to 300 and -300 it spit out 3 cell. ( 0, 1, 2, 3), (4, 0,
2, 3) and (1, 4, 2, 3).

//------ update 1.----

So I change the way of extract the vertex. I convert directly from itCell->vertext->point() and I get the vertex I think correctly. But it still give me lot of cell that 
intersect with other cell. I thought the set supposed to be unique and not intersect with other cell.

Answer (score 2):

As documented [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/classCGAL_1_1Delaunay__triangulation__2.html#a2c02556452fea3d9e3f6cbd332d8c126), *this function is not guaranteed to insert the points following the order of PointInputIterator*. You better use [this example](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/Triangulation_2_2info_insert_with_zip_iterator_2_8cpp-example.html) if you want to set indices that match your input. [This one](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/Triangulation_2_2info_insert_with_transform_iterator_2_8cpp-example.html) works too.

The doc of the corresponding function is [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/classCGAL_1_1Delaunay__triangulation__2.html#a0ea76bda5cb948080eebf974af7fc506).

Comment: So u have to sort the point in certain way before you push to the delaunay object?. Btw, I want 3d delaunay. So will this 2d code will work the same way?

Comment: The sorting is indeed done internally to speed up the insertion. 3D works the same.